# What are the main differences between editing with Adobe Lightroom vs Adobe Spark?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing, software-recommendation, adobe

My Chromebook won't allow me to install Lightroom, but I can use Adobe Spark. I'm wondering what are the pros and cons of each of them?

Comment: They can't be reasonably compared. Spark:Lightroom::boat:automobile. They serve completely different functions in completely different domains.

Comment: Maybe try [Polarr](https://www.polarr.co/)?

Comment: More like Spark:Lightroom as Boat:Ice-maker (They both deal with water, but in entirely different ways)

Answer (score 5):

Adobe Lightroom is a streamlined photo processing and organizing software. Adobe Spark is a tool for visual storytelling on the web.

Here's a comparison of the respective pro's and con's:

### Adobe Lightroom

- **Pro:** It's a good program for photo processing and organizing
- **Con:** It's not a tool for visual storytelling on the web

### Adobe Spark

- **Pro:** It's a good tool for visual storytelling on the web
- **Con:** It's not a program for photo processing and organizing

In the end you gotta choose what's right for you and your project.